# Map xml data from arc GIS

Tags: r, plot, arcgis, arcmap

Is it possible to plot/map xml data from arc GIS in R? I have an XML file with a basemap I would like to map in R.

I dont know how to add my XML file to my question but if someone could show me how to plot using this type of file that would be awesome. I usually make my maps in r using ggplot and geom_sf.

```
#How I loaded my XML file into r 
# Load the package required to read XML files.
library("XML")

# Also load the other required package.
library("methods")

# Give the input file name to the function.
result <- xmlParse(file = "Grey background.xml")

# Print the result.
print(result)
```

[image: Example of what basemap looks like in arc GIS]

Comment: Please provide some sample data. I would suggest converting the `xml` into a `shapefile` first and then convert it into an `sf` object using the `sf` package and provide the that object's `dput()` as the sample data in the post.

Comment: For mapping in `R` look into the `geom_sf` function of `ggplot` or `leaflet` if you want an interactive map.